# How to convert function string as real function in Azure COSMOS DB stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to create function dynamically in Azure Cosmos stored procedure using eval or Function constructor.

Let's have an example :

```
let fnStr = "function(){return 1; }" ; // string could contain any thing like a complex function
```

And want to use inside the azure cosmos stored proc

```
let fun =eval(fnStr);
fun();
```

But unfortunately, Azure cosmos does not support "eval" and "Function" constructor.

Do we have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a proper function inside your stored procedure body and invoke it. For example I wrote a function which returns current date/time and then invoked that function from inside stored procedure. Something like:

```
function helloWorld() {

    function getCurrentDate() {
        return new Date();
    }

    var xyz = getCurrentDate();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    response.setBody(xyz);
}
```

Wouldn't something like this work?

Comment: I know this is static way but my function string might come from azure cosmos document or as a stored procedure parameter

Comment: As long as the document is in the same logical partition then you are fine. Stored procedures are scoped to logical partitions in Cosmos DB.

Comment: @MarkBrown I believe the question is how to dynamically create a function inside a stored procedure from a string considering both `eval` and `new Function` are not supported. Do you know if there's some way to import existing node modules (like https for example) using require or import?

Comment: Ah got it. No, that's not possible.